# htaccess authentication password same as user account passwd?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

There are several user accounts on my server. I want to setup htaccess authentication such that username/password is same as individual user's username/password.

So lets say user A logs in the server using password "abcd".
Same combination should be used for htaccess authentication.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**`mod_dbd`**](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_dbd.html#dbdriver) to make Apache connect to any supported database to get authentication info.

Comment: User accounts passwords are stored in database?? :| I guess not!

Can you please provide some code?

Comment: I dont have sql installed on my server. Can "mod_dbd" retrieve info from /etc/passwd and /etc/shadow file as well?

Comment: Hm it wasn't clear in your question. `/etc/passwd` follows different password encryption than apache password file so I am not sure about this.

Comment: Also read this: http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1237269 on why it should not be attempted because of huge security risk.

Comment: This is one way on how to use it: http://www.webhostingtalk.com/showthread.php?t=542543